# How to send JSON to NodeJS Express Server through Postman?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, body-parser

I am trying to send a JSON object through POST from the Chrome app 'Postman'.

If I set the header as `'Content-Type: text/plain'`, then the output at the other side is an empty object:

```
{}
```

If I set the header as `Content-Type: application/json`, I receive the following response...

> 'Error: invalid json'.

The key is set as `ingredients` and the value is set as:

```
{ ["name" : "num1", "quantity" : "5"], ["name" : "num2", "quantity" : "2"], [ "name" : "num3", "quantity" : "8"]}
```

and I catch it here:

```
router.post('/add', jsonParser, function( req, res ) {

     if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);    
     console.log( req.body );
});
```

Comment: can you elaborate what is jsonParser? Is it like `var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all You need to design data as per your Model .
>   Use http://jsoneditoronline.org/ to format Json with out Syntax errors
>
> Step 1:- Set Url parameters (if you have )
>
> Step 2:- Set Standard Http headers
>
> Example:- 1). Content-Type: application/json
>            2). Accept      : application/json
>
> Then Use http CRUD operations as per Your Requirement
>
> You need to send Data to POST and PUT Actions Get - can get the json
>   from api
>
> Post Ex:-  Select Post with API     you see 3 options form-data
>   x-www-form-urlencoded raw Select Option "raw" and Paste your Json content

Good Luck !!

Comment: Do little more research for your Understanding  Buddy Happy Learning !!

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is not valid. Restructure to something that will both parse correctly and work for you to continue. The below example should work fine, where your array of objects are stored in `ingredients`...

```
{
    "ingredients": [{
        "name": "num1",
        "quantity": "5"
    }, {
        "name": "num2",
        "quantity": "2"
    }, {
        "name": "num3",
        "quantity": "8"
    }]
}
```

You can switch this up however you like, just ensure it parses. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) will be your friend for that. Even a plain array without a named identifier will work as well, and the more I look at it, it appears as if you simply had your `{}` and `[]` syntax backwards...

```
[{"name": "num1", "quantity": "5"}, {"name": "num2","quantity": "2"}, {"name": "num3","quantity": "8"}]
```

Comment: This does not work either

    { "ingredients": [{"name" : "num1", "quantity" : "5"}, {"name" : "num2", "quantity" : "2"}, { "name" : "num3", "quantity" : "8"}]}

Comment: I gave you the raw json object. That was the fundamental issue, not how to plug and play with postman. Either way I see you figured it out